# Save data array to CSV file

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fopen

I need to save data array to CSV file. The problem is the following: When I open CSV file, I see that 0 row of an array is saved at the same row as a header. Also the last column of a header contains 0, i.e. 'www0'. How to avoid this?

```
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        saveCSV($solutionCSV);

function saveCSV($data) {
    $outstream = fopen("schedule.csv", "a");

    $headers = 'xxx, yyy, zzz, www';
    fwrite($outstream,$headers);

    function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
        fputcsv($filehandler, $vals);
    }
    array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
    fclose($outstream);
}
```

Comment: This is somewhere where a simple `foreach` would be better than `array_walk()`, especially if you're not using an anonymous function, since a second call to `saveCSV()` will cause a fatal error along the lines of `Cannot redeclare function __outputCSV(), already declared in...`. A `foreach` will be shorter, easier to understand when you come back to the code a year from now and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a newline after the headers. Note the change from single- to double-quotes to enable escaping.

```
$headers = "xxx, yyy, zzz, www\n";
```

If this trips up Windows, use `\r\n`:

```
$headers = "xxx, yyy, zzz, www\r\n";
```

Alternatively, you can rely on `fputcsv` to write the headers, too. This is probably the safest method as it will result in a consistent format.

```
$headers = array('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'www');
fputcsv($outstream, $headers);
```

Comment: Your second solution works fine for me. The last one does not work, I don't know why - It writes Array0 in the first row.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos - Did you change `fwrite` to `fputcsv` when trying that last version?